# Microsoft Graph API: "ErrorDuplicateTransactionId" during event restore

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, microsoft-graph-mail

If we try to restore an existing event to the same calendar, now we got the following with error code  `ErrorDuplicateTransactionId` and error message `Your request can't be completed. The TransactionId specified in the request has already been used to create a different event.`

The error appeared only some time ago - before that duplicate event restore worked just fine.

Event restore request, which is used: `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/Users/user_id/calendars/calendar_id/events`

My questions are:

1. Is it known issue on Microsoft side?
2. Is it documented somewhere on Microsoft side?
3. Can we restore duplicate event to the same calendar?

Comment: I get the same when building some tests to populate test mailboxes with calendar events. I run the requests in batches but set the transaction ID to the same value for them all, so that I can search for the events created for the test and delete them easily later. It creates over a hundred with the same transaction ID and then throws this error saying duplicate transaction ID which makes no sense when it's being allowing it.

Comment: Noting in production code I generate a unique transaction ID per event request. The transaction ID is being used for tracking on individual events in that case. I was hoping to use it to track a test session however. If not I'll have to use some other field or a common value in the subject.

Answer (score 0):

- There is no restore functionality available for events. Its only available to Groups, users, application. Here's the documentation [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directory-deleteditems-restore?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).
- I see that what you're trying to do is making POST call of the event. The error is telling that the event id is used by something event in the calendar, so you can't use it or you're trying to create a duplicate event with the same event id (which was used by other event). You can validate this checking your calendar events, the eventid might be used by some other event. In such scenario, i would try creating a new event (don't use the old event id). This will help you move forward to overcome the error.